# Testing python project with nosetest and pytest together

Tags: pytest, nose

I've got a project with quite a bit set of UT written with nosetest. I'd like to add the UI testing using Selenium and Pytest. Is it possible to use these two frameworks together? Can I just add the other test folder and run one test suit using nosetest and the other one using pytest? I would rather not to touch existing UT tests for now. Could you point me in a right direction?

Comment: `pytest` can run nose tests out of the box, so there's nothing to do. Use `pytest` as the default test runner and you should be good to go. If there are any issues running the tests, update your question with a [mcve].